# use setpci to restart ubuntu server after power failure on macbook

Tags: server, reboot, bios, power-management

I installed ubuntu server 11.10 on my macbook 1,1.

In order to reboot after power failure I have to set a specific "AFTERG3" bit using setpci.

The solution for a macMini can be found here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/203522/reboot-after-power-failure-for-mac-running-ubuntu-server

Does anybody have an idea how to find out the corresponding command for my hardware?

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
setpci -s 00:1f.0 0xa4.b=0
```

The poster in my linked question just forgot one 0.

Comment: Great work on figuring this out yourself. You should accept your own answer here (by clicking the tick on the left) so people in the future will know to read this one.

Answer (score 4):

Just a minor correction: 
After checking the setpci command, it would be more appropriate to use

```
setpci -s 0:1f.0 0xa4.b=0:1
```

as this will only set bit zero to zero (0 = value : 1 = masq ).

It does not matter in this case since all the other 7 bits of pci `0:1f.0` address `0xa4` are already zero, but that might not be the case for other hardware.

Use the `sudo lspci -vvvxxx` command to see what your `0:1f.0` pci device initial configuration is before making any mods.

Answer (score 3):

The technical reason for using the `setpci -s 0:1f.0 0xa4.b=0` magic is described here:

http://smackerelofopinion.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/mac-mini-rebooting-tweaks-setpci-s-01f0.html